# Seo-friendly url in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, url, routes, seo

I've created a filter method for filtering the products list. This is my URL:

```
localhost/myshop/products/filter?category=shirts&color=blue&page=1
```

But I want to show this way:

```
localhost/myshop/products/shirts/blue/1
```

How can I achieve it?

Comment: What is controller name in first URL?

Comment: Please provide the code you have tried so others can help you.

Comment: sorry, I forget it. It's products.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `Products::filter()` is responsible for handling the request, you can rewrite the method to accept parameters in its signature. So, if the current logic is something like this:

```
class Products extends CI_Controller
{
    public function filter()
    {
        // Retrieve data from GET params
        $page     = $this->input->get('page');
        $color    = $this->input->get('color');
        $category = $this->input->get('category');
    
        // Do the filtering with $category, $color and $page...
    }
}
```

You can simply refactor it to accept parameters through URL segments:

```
public function filter($category, $color, $page)
{        
    // Do the filtering with $category, $color and $page...
}
```

With this in place, your current URL is:

```
localhost/myshop/products/filter/shirts/blue/1
```

We need to get rid of that extra `filter/` and we're done, right? Quoting from the [docs](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html):

> Typically there is a one-to-one relationship between a URL string and its corresponding controller class/method. The segments in a URI normally follow this pattern:
>
> `example.com/class/method/param1/param2`
>
> In some instances, however, **you may want to remap this relationship so that a different class/method can be called instead** of the one corresponding to the URL.

OK, so we need to remap the current route. You have a few options:

- First, is to update your `application/config/routes.php` file with a new entry:

  ```
    $route['products/(:any)'] = 'products/filter/$1';
  ```

  It says that if a URL starts with `products/`, remap it to the `filter` method of `products` class.

  Here you can use wildcards and regex patterns to be even more precise about the type of parameters your method accepts.
- Another option is that you might want to implement a [`_remap()`](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/controllers.html#remapping-method-calls) method in your controller in order to do the route remapping for you.

Comment: Awesome!! It's perfect!! Thanks, but how can avoid if one of the params is empty? For instance: localhost/myshop/products/filter/blue/1

Comment: It's ok. If either one or more parameters are empty, CodeIgniter will throw a `ArgumentCountError` exception for your. If either one or more of parameters contain illegal characters, you'll get a `400 Bad Request`. So, basically, you're safe against those threats.

Comment: Even in the `routes.php` file, you can specify wildcards/regex patterns to match and guard the params. Say, for example, you want the `$page` to always be a number: `$route['products/(:any)/(:any)/(:num)'] = 'products/filter/$1/$2/$3';`. Read more about this in the [routing docs](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html).

Answer (score 0):

in `routes.php` file, you can write following line

```
    $route['products/(:any)/(:any)/(:num)'] = 'products/filter/$1/$2/$3';
```

and function will be like following

```
    public function filter($category, $color, $page)
    {        
        echo $category.'<br>';
        echo $color.'<br>';         
        echo $page.'<br>';
    }
```